# Call Groovy builder from Java

Tags: java, groovy, builder, auto-value

I'm trying to use Groovy (which is new to me) to replace Java value object classes with a Groovy equivalent and thus obtain a cleaner and more concise code, while remaining compatible with the rest of the Java codebase. (if this attempt fails, I may fall back to Google `@AutoValue`.)

The value objects shall remain instantiable from Java code using the builder pattern. The setter methods shall be without prefix and ideally the builder should be instantiable through a static method with configurable name.

`@groovy.transform.builder.Builder`'s Javadoc mentions it can be used "if you need Java integration" and I see it also has configuration parameters which looks promising, but I did not figure out how to use it from Java code.

Here is an attempt, where I do not know what to substitute for X:

Greeting.groovy:

```
import groovy.transform.Immutable
import groovy.transform.builder.Builder

@Immutable
@Builder
public class GroovyGreeting {
  String message
}
```

GroovyGreetingTest.java:

```
GroovyGreeting g = X.message("foo").build();
```

EDIT: 2 classes are generated, `target/classes/com/hello/GroovyGreeting.class` and `target/classes/com/hello/GroovyGreeting$com/hello/GroovyGreetingBuilder.class`. The '$' in there is really strange and prevents referencing it (`import com.hello.GroovyGreeting$com.hello.GroovyGreetingBuilder` is illegal). Also for some reason in IntelliJ IDEA I can decompile `GroovyGreetingBuilder.class` but not `GroovyGreeting.class` (no reaction when trying to open it).

Comment: I assume you've tried `GroovyGreeting.builder().message("foo").build()`?

Comment: Yes, that doesn't work.

Answer (score 3):

I had exactly the same problem. After investigating the code of the Builder strategies, I managed to make it work by explicitly specifying the builderClassName.

```
package alfa.beta

@Builder(builderClassName = 'PageLayoutBuilder')
class PageLayout
```

I can see that the generated builder is alfa/beta/PageLayout$PageLayoutBuilder now.

I filed a JIRA issue GROOVY-7501 for this.

Comment: Thanks a lot (sorry for late reply). Do you happen to have a working maven project setup? Can't get this working any more :/